# How do I send JSON to an external API using RestEasy?

Tags: java, json, resteasy

I need to send a JSON body to https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0//messages/send-template.json . How do I do this using RestEasy in Java? This is what I have so far:

```
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target("https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0//messages/send-template.json");
```

How do I actually send the JSON?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the `ResteasyWebTarget`, you need to get the `Invocation`

```
Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = target.request("text/plain").header("some", "header");
Invocation incovation = invocationBuilder.buildPost(someEntity);
invocation.invoke();
```

where `someEntity` is some instance of [`Entity<?>`](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-beta-4/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/Entity.html). Create one with

```
Entity<String> someEntity = Entity.entity(someJsonString, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

[Read this javadoc.](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-beta-4/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/Invocation.Builder.html)

*This is for 3.0 beta 4.*

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old question, but I found it looking for something similar on Google, so this is my solution, using RestEasy client 3.0.16:

I'll use a Map object to be sent but you can use whatever JavaBean that  [Jackson provider](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) can convert to JSON.

BTW, you'll need add as dependency the resteasy-jackson2-provider lib.

```
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target("http://server:port/api/service1");
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("field1", "this is a test");
data.put("num_field2", 125);
Response r = target.request().post( Entity.entity(data, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
if (r.getStatus() == 200) {
    // Ok
} else {
    // Error on request
    System.err.println("Error, response: " + r.getStatus() + " - "+ r.getStatusInfo().getReasonPhrase());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this framework, but according to an example at [this url](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.2.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#RESTEasy_Client_Framework), you should be able to make a call like this:

```
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
        WebTarget target = client.target("http://foo.com/resource");
        Response response = target.request().get();
        String value = response.readEntity(String.class);
        response.close();  // You should close connections!
```

The 3rd line seems to be the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you. I've been to that website multiple times, but I'm more interested in SENDING information via POST than I am in the response.

Comment: This *is* sending.  The only difference for what you want is it's calling `request().get()` instead of `request().buildPost(...)`.  The javadoc for `buildPost` is here: http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-beta-1/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/Invocation.Builder.html#buildPost(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity)